# How to correlate a function having dynamic boundaries in Loadrunner?

Tags: regex, correlation, loadrunner

I have a boundary -

li class=" requestEnt no-main-scroll " data-toggle='slidePanel' data-cache="true" data-catalog='4614' data-key="5394" data-displayname="110G - RPS Austin Trading - General" data-description="Grants access to manually enter trades into STAR." data-type="Entitlement"

Here I would like to capture data-displayname, data-catalog and data-key using web_reg_save_param_regexp function. 
How do i correlate it?

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to do:

```
  web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=DataCatalog",
    "RegExp=data-catalog='([0-9]*)'”,
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    LAST);
```

etc... for the other two.

If you want to be more sophisticated and rely on the order of elements in the response you can do:

```
  web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=DataCatalog",
    "RegExp=data-catalog='([0-9]*)' data-key=\"([0-9]*)\" data-displayname=\"(.*)\" data-description",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    "Group=1",
    LAST);

  web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=DataKey",
    "RegExp=data-catalog='([0-9]*)' data-key=\"([0-9]*)\" data-displayname=\"(.*)\" data-description",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    "Group=2",
    LAST);

  web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=DataDisplayName",
    "RegExp=data-catalog='([0-9]*)' data-key=\"([0-9]*)\" data-displayname=\"(.*)\" data-description",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    "Group=3",
    LAST);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to do it with *web_reg_save_param_regexp* is

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=dataCatalog",
   "RegExp=data-catalog='(.*?)'",
   SEARCH_FILTERS,
   "Scope=Body",
    LAST);

web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=displayName",
   "RegExp=data-displayname=\"(.*?)\"",
   SEARCH_FILTERS,
   "Scope=Body",
   LAST);

web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=dataKey",
   "RegExp=data-key=\"(.*?)\"",
   SEARCH_FILTERS,
   "Scope=Body",
   LAST);
```

which are almost similar to *web_reg_save_param* used below

```
web_reg_save_param("dataCatalog",
   "LB=data-catalog='",
   "RB='",
   "Search=body",
   LAST);

web_reg_save_param("displayName",
  "LB=data-displayname=\"",
  "RB=\"",
  "Search=body",
  LAST);

web_reg_save_param("dataKey",
  "LB=data-key=\"",
  "RB=\"",
  "Search=body",
  LAST);
```

Both capture the values ***dataCatalog*** as ***4614***, ***displayName*** as ***110G - RPS Austin Trading - General*** and ***dataKey*** as ***5394*** in case of above provided response.

Looking at the response provided, boundaries do not look dynamic. It would be more helpful if could you give some more responses of the same request.